# How to handle order of operations when making a trigonometric calculator

Tags: java

Update: Unfortunately i was unable to finish this assignment, although the deadline has passed i feel that i have invested too much time on this to just set it aside and i know that I am close to the solution. This is the code that i have produced over the past couple of days

```
/* 

 "[5*sin(3*t+0.523),4*cos(2*t)]"

*/

import java.util.*;             // 
import javax.swing.*;           // 
import javax.swing.JFrame;      // lets me create the window 
import java.awt.Graphics;       // for drawing 
import java.awt.Point;          // allows the use of points 
import java.awt.Graphics2D;     // for drawing 
import javax.swing.JComponent;  // for drawing 
import javax.swing.JPanel;     // for drawing 
import java.lang.Math;         // for trig 
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;




public class Graph 
{   

//-------------------Queue---String----------------------------------------------------------------//

  public static double[] queue_str(String str, double[] results)
  {
    Queue<Character> token = new LinkedList<Character>();
    Queue<Double> numbers = new LinkedList<Double>();
    double[] t_vals = new double [5];
    int t_vals_len = t_vals.length;
    int numbers_sz = 0;
    int token_sz = 0;
    t_vals[0] = 7.0;
    t_vals[1] = 2.0;
    t_vals[2] = 3.0;
    t_vals[3] = 4.0;
    t_vals[4] = 3.0;
    char temp_token;
    char temp_char; 
    double p1_num = 0, temp_num = 0, p2_num = 0;

    if(results.length == 0){}

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i) == '*' && str.charAt(i) != 't'  || str.charAt(i) == '+'&& str.charAt(i) != 't' || str.charAt(i) == '-' && str.charAt(i) != 't' || str.charAt(i) == '/' && str.charAt(i) != 't')
        {
            temp_token = str.charAt(i);
            token.add(temp_token);
            token_sz ++;
            String[] parts = str.split("\\" + String.valueOf(temp_token));
            String str1 = parts[0];
            String str2 = parts[1];


            if(str1.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))
            {
                p1_num = Double.parseDouble(str1);
                numbers.add(p1_num);
                numbers_sz ++;
            }

            if(str2.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))
            {
                p2_num = Double.parseDouble(str2);
                numbers.add(p2_num);
                numbers_sz ++;
            }
        }
            else if(str.charAt(i) == 't')
            {
                temp_token = str.charAt(i);

                String [] t_char = str.split(String.valueOf(temp_token));

                for(int k = 0; k < t_vals_len; k++)
                {
                    temp_num = t_vals[k];
                    numbers.add(temp_num);
                    numbers_sz ++;
                }
            }

    }
      double[] dbl_numbs = new double [numbers_sz];

      while(numbers.peek()!=null)
      {
           for (int iter = 0; iter < numbers_sz; iter++)
           {
             dbl_numbs [iter] = numbers.poll();
           }  
      }

         while(token.peek()!=null)
          {
               temp_token = token.peek();
               token.poll();

               if(temp_token== '+')
               {

                 eval_inner_add(dbl_numbs, numbers_sz);
                 results = eval_inner_add(dbl_numbs,numbers_sz);

               }
               else if(temp_token == '-')
               {

                eval_inner_add(dbl_numbs, numbers_sz);
               }
               else if(temp_token == '*')
               {
                 results  = eval_inner_multi(dbl_numbs, numbers_sz);

               }
               else if(temp_token == '/')
               {

                eval_inner_div(dbl_numbs, numbers_sz);
               }
          }

      return t_vals;
  }
//-----------------Removing---Brackets-------------------------------------------------------------//  
  public static String [] remove_brackets(String remove_brack)
  {
     String [] substring = remove_brack.split ("[\\[,\\]]");
     String rest_of_str = substring [1];
     String rest_of_str_2 = substring [2];
     return new String [] {rest_of_str,rest_of_str_2};
  } 
//-----------------Removing---Parenthesis-------------------------------------------------------------//    
   public static String [] remove_paren(String remove_paren)
  {
     String [] substring = remove_paren.split ("[\\(,\\)]");
     String rest_of_str = substring [0];
     String rest_of_str_2 = substring [1];
     return new String [] {rest_of_str,rest_of_str_2};
  } 
//---------------Retrieving--Far-Left--Number----------------------------------------------------//  
  public static double get_first_exp (String get_left_exp)  
  {
    double eval_num = 0;

    if(get_left_exp.matches("[-]"))
    {
        String [] check_neg = get_left_exp.split("[\\-]");
        String neg_num = check_neg[0];
        eval_num = Double.parseDouble(neg_num);
        eval_num = eval_num * (-1.0);
        return eval_num;
    }
    else
    {
        String [] parts = get_left_exp.split("[\\/,\\*,\\+]");
        String sub_str_1 = parts [0];
        eval_num = Double.parseDouble(sub_str_1);
        return eval_num;
    }
  }
//-------------Evaluating--equations--containing--sine----------------------------------------//

  public static double eval_sin (String sin_eq)
  {
   double number = 0;
   String [] split = remove_paren(sin_eq);
   String inner_exp = split[1];
   double [] nothing = new double [0];

   number = get_first_exp (sin_eq);
   queue_str(inner_exp, nothing);
   return number;
  }

//-------------Evaluating--equations--containing--cosine----------------------------------------//
  public static double eval_cos (String cos_eq)
  {
   double number = 0;
   double [] nothing = new double [0];
   String [] split = remove_paren(cos_eq);
   String inner_exp = split[1];

   number = get_first_exp (cos_eq);
   queue_str(inner_exp, nothing);
   return number;
  }
//---------------Evalutating--points-------------------------------------------------------------//  
  public static double[] eval_inner_multi (double [] numbers, int numbers_sz)
  {
   String nothing  = "";
   double[] results = new double [numbers_sz];
   double  first_num = numbers[0];
   System.out.println(first_num);

    for(int i = 1; i < numbers_sz-1; i++)
    {
     results[i] = first_num * numbers[i]; 
     System.out.println(results[i]);
    }
      queue_str(nothing,results);
      return results; 
  }

  public static double[] eval_inner_add (double [] numbers, int numbers_sz)
  {
   String nothing  = "";
   double[] results = new double [numbers_sz];
   double  first_num = numbers[0];


    for(int i = 1; i < numbers_sz-1; i++)
    {
     results[i] = first_num + numbers[i]; 
     System.out.println(results[i]);
    }
      queue_str(nothing,results);
      return results; 
  }

  public static double[] eval_inner_sub(double [] numbers, int numbers_sz)
  {
   double[] t_vals = new double [5];
   return t_vals; 
  }

  public static double[] eval_inner_div(double [] numbers,int numbers_sz)
  {
   double[] t_vals = new double [5];
   return t_vals; 
  }
//------------------------------Main------------------------------------------------------------------------//  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      String left_exp = "";
      String right_exp = "";
      double left_sin_num , right_sin_num, left_cos_num, right_cos_num = 0;

      for(String s: args)  // taking in user input for command line 
      {
           String [] new_str  =  remove_brackets(s);
           left_exp = new_str[0];
           right_exp = new_str[1];
      }

      if(left_exp.contains("sin")) // add SINE, SIN, COSINE, COS
      {
           left_sin_num = eval_sin(left_exp);
      }
      else if (right_exp.contains("sin"))
      {
           right_sin_num = eval_sin(right_exp);
      }
      if (right_exp.contains("cos"))
      {
           right_cos_num = eval_cos(right_exp);
      }
      else if (left_exp.contains("cos"))
      {
           left_cos_num = eval_cos(left_exp);
      }

    }
```

}

The purpose of this assignment was to create a program that evaluates parametric equations and joins the coordinates for plotting a graph. The problem that i have is when i send my array of doubles in the queue_str() function to get evaluated, the instance where i have two operations present stumps we. I cannot properly send the contents back to the queue_str() to be evaluated by the second operand for example take into account the example function in my top comments i am able to send 3*t where t_vals are test cases to be multiplied by the three. In this case i have to go size of array -1 because i have to take into account the first and last element in the array. This is where im stuck how can I properly evaluate this expression? I would appreciate any help and i apologize for this paragraph, i just know im so close to getting this to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should parse your expression into a tree, instead of evaluating them from left to right.

```
  sin
   |
   +
  / \
  *  5
 / \
2  t
```

This is explained in more detail [here](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs135/handouts/08-trees-post3up.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I was solving a similar problem to yours, and to get the order of everything right I used a lexer and parser - in Python, I used PLY, which is very well documented here http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html

In the documentation, here is a good illustration of what goes on 'behind the scenes' during a parser: http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn22

My tokenizer/parser structure was inspired by the same structure Java uses to evaluate its expressions. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8

If you've never wrapped your mind around a parser structure before, there are a few things to get used to. Such as:

-A root token - call it expression - that can be promoted to from a number or name or functional call or any other 'component', and 'grows' to 'consume' the entire structure by allowing everything else to be folded into it.

-Multiple levels of promoted token that a raw number or name passes through before becoming an expression - each stage to see if an operator, from unary to higher precedence to lower precedence, can be applied against it before allowing it to be promoted again. A parser like YACC makes this work by only applying a rule if it can pick the largest or otherwise knows its pick will be unambiguous, else it takes more tokens from the tokenizer before making its decision.

-The recursive nature of it - what's inside of sin(...) is an argument list, which is an expression or argumentlist,expression, and expression itself can be as complex as the outer expression... and once the function call happens, it will be promoted into an expression itself after checking against all the precedence levels of operators! And so on.

In general, I'd read the documentation on PLY as it'll help you wrap your head around all of this :) You just CAN'T do expression calculation by raw string/substring operations without tokenizing and parsing, I tried really hard but there was always some edge case that fooled me.